# Coroutine what is the difference with C++ inline function?

Tags: coroutine

As I understood it, coroutine is a sequence of function calls, with the difference that function calls do not allocate stack each call (they are resumed for the point they were stoped), or we can say that these function are executed in shared stack.

So the main advantage of coroutine is execution speed. Isn't it just inline functions from C++? (when instead of call, function body is inserted during compilation).

Answer (score 3):

A "coroutine", in the commonly used sense, is basically a function that -- once started -- can be envisioned as running alongside the caller.  That is, when the coroutine "yields" (a semi-special kind of return), it isn't necessarily done -- and "calling" it again will have the coroutine pick up right where it left off, with all its state intact, rather than starting from the beginning.  The calls can thus be seen as kinda passing messages between the two functions.

Few languages fully and natively do this.  (Stack-based languages tend to have a hard time with it, absent some functionality like Windows's "fibers".)  Ruby does, apparently, and Python uses a limited version of it.  I believe they call it a "generator", and it's basically used kinda like an iterable collection (whose iterator generates its next "element" on the fly).  C# can semi do that as well (they call it an "iterator"), but the compiler actually turns the function into a class that implements a state machine of sorts.

Comment: And what is an advantage of this? Why not create class with this function call and store its state.

Comment: @Alex: It's extra code that doesn't need to be there if the language supports coroutines.  Like i said, C# actually does exactly that -- it converts a function that contains a `yield return` statement to a class that stores the state between calls and jumps to the right resume point via a `switch` statement.  Calling the function returns an `IEnumerable`, and each time you get the next value from the enumerator, it "resumes".  You could do something like that yourself, but if the language will do it for you....why not?  :)